# Get product id in magento

Tags: php, magento

In magento,i want to add quick look feature like this http://www.timberlandonline.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-TBLGB-Site/default/Link-Category?cgid=men_footwear_boots.I have added a hidden input & a div in list.phtml.If i click the div of any product javascript returns product id of first product in that category page.But it should return product id of the selected div.

Comment: Your URL directs to 404 page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to look into this page (`<path_to_your_template_folder>/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`) carefully. You will find the following lines of code in different places of this page only:-

```
$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
    $reqProductId = $_product->getId();
endforeach;
```

If you carefully match the above code & the code in the above-mentioned page, you will know that you need to use the variable "`$reqProductId`" properly in your required "`INPUT`" element of type "`hidden`". So you will require it to do your part in the main "`foreach`" loop.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.I stored each product id in ID of anchor tag and fetched the id using jquery.I will try this method too.

Comment: Any idea how to get product ID in admin panel / catalog / manage product ? ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499447/get-product-id-in-admin-panel

Answer (score 4):

**Try below code to get currently loaded product id:**

```
$product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
```

When you don’t have access to `$this`, you can use Magento registry:

```
$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
```

Also for product type i think

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); 

$productType = $product->getTypeID();
```