# Get product ID in Admin Panel

Tags: magento

How to get current product ID in Admin Panel / Catalog / Manage Products / Tab ?

[image]

I have a custom product tab and no idea how to get current product ID.

In frontend I would do something like this:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController` you will see the product in question twice, so either of these will work:

```
$product = Mage::registry('product');
echo $product->getId();

$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
echo $product->getId();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the product ID in the URL:

http://yourmagento.install.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/[here_it_is]/key/35db6b1fdadbcf2867d06150blahblahblahblahblahc19697f1a28cd141051/

Failing that, I'll have a look at what template file you'll need to edit.

EDIT:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml
```

After this line:

```
<h3 class="icon-head head-products"><?php echo $this->getHeader() ?></h3>
```

Put this:

```
<?php if($this->getProductId()){ echo $this->getProductId(); } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam(’id’);
```