# how to map the different affiliate products in magento if the feed doesn't have MPN/UPC?

Tags: javascript, php, magento, barcode, datafeed

I have different affiliate products like Flipkart and snapdeal but the feeds doesn't have MPN or any other unique identifier.How can we Map them for price comparison?

Like, LG nexus 5 and Google LG Nexus 5 should be mapped to a single product.

Comment: What data feed are you referring to?

Comment: Flipkart and Snapdeal data feeds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into this page
(`<path_to_your_template_folder>/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`) carefully.
You will find the following lines of code in different places of this page only:-

```
$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
    $reqProductId = $_product->getId();
endforeach;
```

If you carefully match the above code & the code in the above-mentioned page,
you will know that you need to use the variable `$reqProductId` properly in your required `INPUT` element of type `hidden`.
So you will require it to do your part in the main `foreach` loop.

Any idea how to get product ID in admin panel / catalog / manage product: 
[Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499447/get-product-id-in-admin-panel)

Comment: Thank you,i have managed to display product information but i want to get the MPN or unique identifier for price comparison of different affiliate products.But data feeds doesn't have MPN or UPC or any other unique identifier which is common in all product feeds.